# My Custom View will not load

Tags: java, android, layout, android-custom-view

I created a custom view extended from the view class.  It loads just fine if I call

`setContentView(new Customview());`

However it will not load from the xml layout file.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ThumbnailTest">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.example.christopher.thumbnailtest.ThumbnailFrame
    class="com.example.christopher.thumbnailtest.ThumbnailFrame"
    id="@+id/ThumbnailFrame"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

It is just a simple circle, that is all I'm trying to draw.

**EDIT:**  Here is the custom view class.  Now the view class gets called, but the circle is not printing a circle on screen.  The first two parameters of the `drawCircle()` method were very high (reported from the debug log WHAT) but I divided the numbers to bring them down and they still showed nothing.  It's like the function won't paint the object on canvas when it is loaded as a view from the layout file.

```
public class ThumbnailFrame extends View {

    private Paint thumbnailPaint;
    private Canvas thumbnailCanvas;

    private float xMax;
    private float yMax;
    private float xMin;
    private float yMin;

    private float PositX;
    private float PositY;

    private float radius;

    public ThumbnailFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        thumbnailPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        thumbnailPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        thumbnailPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        //Default radius
        radius = 20;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w,
                                 int h,
                                 int oldw,
                                 int oldh) {

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        Log.d("FRAME_CALLED", "I'm called!");

        float xpad = (float)(getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight());
        float ypad = (float)(getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom());

        float ww = (float)w - xpad;
        float hh = (float)h - ypad;

        xMax = ww - radius;
        xMin = ww + radius;

        yMax = hh - radius;
        yMin = hh + radius;

        PositX = ww/2;
        PositY = hh/2;

    }

    public void redraw() {
        Log.d("THUMBNAIL_CALLED", "Am I called?");
        //Make sure our circle does not leave the bounds of our screen.
        if (PositX > xMax) {
            PositX = xMax;
        }
        if (PositX < xMin) {
            PositX = xMin;
        }
        if (PositY > yMax) {
            PositY = yMax;
        }
        if (PositY < yMin) {
            PositY = yMin;
        }

        Log.d("WHAT", String.valueOf(PositX) + ":" + String.valueOf(PositY) + ":" + String.valueOf(radius) + ":" + thumbnailPaint.toString());

        thumbnailCanvas.drawCircle(PositX, PositY, 100, thumbnailPaint);
    }

    public void setRadius(float value) {
        radius = value;
    }

    public void setFrameX(float x) {
        PositX = x;
    }

    public void setFrameY(float y) {
        PositY = y;
    }

    public void removeFrame() {
        thumbnailCanvas.save();
        thumbnailCanvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        Log.d("THUMBNAIL_CALLED", "Am I called?");

        thumbnailCanvas = canvas;

        redraw();
    }
```

}

Comment: It does not show up entirely.  There's no error in logcat.  It does call the debug statements from the custom view class, but it still won't display.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that, but the circle doesn't print even if I remove PositX and PositY and place my floats in.  It still won't make a circle.  It works when not done through the xml layout file, but when put into the layout file it just can't load into the view.    :(

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as you wrote.
You just don't see yellow on white because it has small width.
I suggest add `thumbnailPaint.setStrokeWidth(10f/*or what you want*/);` in constructor:

```
 public ThumbnailFrame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        thumbnailPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        thumbnailPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        thumbnailPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        thumbnailPaint.setStrokeWidth(10f);

        //Default radius
        radius = 20;

    }
```

also you should change layout from:

```
<com.example.christopher.thumbnailtest.ThumbnailFrame
    class="com.example.christopher.thumbnailtest.ThumbnailFrame"
    id="@+id/ThumbnailFrame"
    android:layout_width="265dp"
    android:layout_height="230dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

to:

```
<com.example.christopher.thumbnailtest.ThumbnailFrame
        android:id="@+id/ThumbnailFrame"
        android:layout_width="265dp"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Also you should call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main/*your id*/);` instead of `setContentView(new Customview());`

After that you can see:

[image]

Comment: I set the width to 20 and changed the color to red, but it still won't show up on the screen.  I only see the text box, no custom view nearby.

Comment: @user3210277 I post my screenshot with your view. Please re-check.

Comment: Ah it does work, thanks!  So what happened is I had another constructor set for ThumbnailFrame(context) and the XML was calling ThumbnailFrame(Context, attributeSet).  The width and color changes I made were to the first so the circle was only showing up when the object was directly called with setViewContent().  Thanks so much!